# How to apply IAM Role to EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I launched a EC2 instance with no IAM Roles at the beginning.
Now I want to add a IAM Role to the EC2 instance.
So how can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add IAM role to an existing instance in aws?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913966/how-to-add-iam-role-to-an-existing-instance-in-aws)

Comment: As of AWS CLI v1.11.46, you can do that. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42165849/3770040).

Answer (score 3):

Now you can associate with the new update AWS has come up.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/new-attach-an-aws-iam-role-to-an-existing-amazon-ec2-instance-by-using-the-aws-cli/?sc_channel=sm&sc_campaign=launch_Identity_and_Access_888972a0&sc_publisher=fb_ln&sc_content=Roles_for_Running_Instances_CLI_SDK&sc_geo=global&sc_outcome=launches&adbsc=social_launches_20170210_69995676&adbid=1211418348895528&adbpl=fb&adbpr=153063591397681

Comment: With the aws cli, you now can.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the aws cli.  There's [a howto blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/new-attach-an-aws-iam-role-to-an-existing-amazon-ec2-instance-by-using-the-aws-cli/) available here.